# What happens when memory "wraps" on an IA-32 supporting machine?

Tags: memory, x86

I'm creating a 64-bit model of IA-32 and am representing memory as a 0-based array of `2**64` bytes (the language I'm modeling this in uses `**` as the exponentiation operator). This means that valid indices into the array are from `0` to `2**64-1`. Now, to model the possible modes of accessing that memory, one can treat one element as an 8-bit number, two elements as a (little-endian) 16-bit number, etc.

My question is, what should my model do if they ask for a 16-bit (or 32-bit, etc.) number from location `2**64-1`? Right now, what the model does is say that the returned value is `Memory(2**64-1) + (8 * Memory(0))`. I'm not updating any flags (which feels wrong). Is wrapping like this the correct behavior? Should I be setting any flags when the wrapping happens?

I have a copy of Intel-64-ia-32-ISA.pdf which I'm using as a reference, but it's 1,479 pages, and I'm having a hard time finding the answer to this particular question.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you mean bit a couple of times you used "byte".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested it (did anyone expect that?) for 64bit numbers with this code:

```
mov dword [0], 0xDEADBEEF
mov dword [-4], 0x01020304
mov rdi, [-4]
call writelonghex
```

In a custom OS, with pages mapped as appropriate, running in VirtualBox. `writelonghex` just writes `rdi` to the screen as a 16-digit hexadecimal number. The result: [image: deadbeef01020304]

So yes, it does just wrap. Nothing funny happens.

No flags should be affected (though the manual doesn't say that no flags should be set for address wrapping, it does say that `mov reg, [mem]` doesn't affect them *ever*, and that includes this case), and no interrupt/trap/whatever happens (unless of course one or both pages touched are not present).

Comment: Excellent. This definitely is a simpler implementation than I would've expected. I'll accept this as the answer in a little while if no one else provides a reason that your answer is wrong. (Testing is excellent, and I like that you mention that `mov reg, [mem]` should never set any flags, but I just want to wait to see if possibly the system you're testing with isn't implemented correctly, however unlikely that is.)

Answer (score 2):

The answer is in Volume 3A, section 5.3: "Limit checking."

For ia-32:

> When the effective limit is FFFFFFFFH (4 GBytes), these accesses [which extend beyond the end of the segment] may or may not cause the indicated exceptions. Behavior is implementation-specific and may vary from one execution to another.

For ia-64:

> In 64-bit mode, the processor does not perform rumtime limit checking on code or data segments. Howver, the processor does check descriptor-table limits.